# compile with intel compiler 12 for windows using boost 1.51 error

Tags: c++, windows, boost, intel

i like to checkout how intel compiler performs in comparison to VS2008.
So i installed intel composer xe 12 and used intel compiler for my projects.
Also i built all boost libs with intel compiler:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE\bin\compilervars.bat" ia32 vs2008
call bootstrap.bat
call bjam --toolset="intel" --build-dir="libs"  --stagedir="win32" --build-type=complete stage  threading=multi link=static runtime-link=static
```

The problem: when set in project

c/c++ - language - Enable Runtime Type info = no

i get a compiler error in

```
boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp(153)
```

When set

c/c++ - language - Enable Runtime Type info = yes

i get my application compiled and linked but now get a runtime error in

boost/thread/win32/thread_primitives.hpp

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'ret' is being used without being initialized.
```

Anyone can help to resolve this ?

Comment: `--toolset="intel"` is wrong, since `toolset` is a feature rather than a bjam option; try `toolset="intel"`, sans dashes, and see if that works.

Comment: Hello, the problem is not in the boost lib build. sample from intel site: bjam --Build-dir="C:\ Program Files\boost\boost_1_37_0\intel" --toolset=intel --build-type=complete stage

Comment: The problem _could_ be with the way Boost was built – if it was built with a different toolchain than you're using to link to it, who knows how that might manifest. In any case, the example from Intel's site is wrong; it should be `toolset=intel`, not `--toolset=intel`.

Comment: so i replaced --toolset by toolset and at least the size of boost libs is the same as when built with --toolset. Just for clarification: the boost build get's completed and linking my apps to new libs is successful when set c/c++ - language - Enable Runtime Type info = yes. But in this case, i get a runtime error about variable used before initialization in one of the boost libs. When set c/c++ - language - Enable Runtime Type info = no, i get a compiler error when building my apps (not the boost lib).

Comment: I've got the exact same runtime error in boost, same compiler. Did you manage to solve it by chance ?